# How to map Join table as Entity JPA

Tags: java, jpa

In my system, I have `User` and `User` can be a `Manager` or a client or even bought. `Manager` can have many `Clients` and `Client` can have many managers. `Manager` is represented by `manager_id` in `managers_clients`, so if `User` is a manager we will store his id to that column. And the same goes for the client.

My database tables look like this:

```
users (table)
UUID  FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME
1   Bob     Way
2   Sarah   Smith

managers_clients (table)
ID  MANAGER_ID CLIENT_ID
1   1          1
2   1          2
```

Now here `MANAGER_ID` and `CLIENT_ID` are reference to `users.id`

I know that is possible to create a 3rd entity `Manager` and tie them up with this pivot table... But I'm trying to achieve without it.

My current entities look like this:

```
public class UserEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
  private UUID uuid;

  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;

  @OneToMany
  private List<ManagerClientEntity> managers;

  @OneToMany
  private List<ManagerClientEntity> clients;
}

public class ManagerClientEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
  private UUID uuid;

  @ManyToOne
  private UserEntity manager;

  @ManyToOne
  private UserEntity client;
}
```

But, of course, it doesn't work...

I`m new to JPA and Java, so can't figure out how should I map my entities?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a Many to Many join between your User and Client. You will not need to manage your bridge table as a separate entity... rather you can use the `@ManyToMany` annotation with a corresponding `@JoinTable` on your `ClientEntity` and `UserEntity`

```
public class UserEntity {
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "manager_client") // specify your bridge table here
  private List<ClientEntity> clients;
}

public class ClientEntity {
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "manager_client")
  private List<UserEntity> users;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. It is a bit challenging but that's why I want to do it.

Comment: In this case, you could specify a `OneToOne` relationship to the manager and client.